# jaxb2-maven-plugin Jakarta and java 11

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xjc

I am trying to migrate to java 11 and jakarta. I need to create java classes from XSD Files as I did in Java EE. I have changed all jaxb imports into jakarta. But I can not make jaxb2 to create classes with jakarta namspace instead of jaxb.
If I add no dependencies to the plugin part then the class will be created with javax namspace, which I do not need and the imports can not be found anyway with Java error: `package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist.`
The generated class is:

```
package org.ttt.raw.reporting.core.fussnote;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType; // I need to have jakarta.xml.bind ... here!
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
/**

    Java-Klasse für FussnoteType complex type.

    Das folgende Schemafragment gibt den erwarteten Content an, der in dieser Klasse enthalten ist.

    <complexType name="FussnoteType">
    <complexContent>

    &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;

      &lt;sequence&gt;

        &lt;element name="FussnoteNummer" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/&gt;

        &lt;element name="FussnoteText" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/&gt;

      &lt;/sequence&gt;

    &lt;/restriction&gt;

    </complexContent>
    </complexType>

*/
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "FussnoteType", propOrder = {
"fussnoteNummer",
"fussnoteText"
})
public class FussnoteType {

@XmlElement(name = "FussnoteNummer", required = true)
protected String fussnoteNummer;
@XmlElement(name = "FussnoteText", required = true)
protected String fussnoteText;

/**
 * Ruft den Wert der fussnoteNummer-Eigenschaft ab.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getFussnoteNummer() {
    return fussnoteNummer;
}

/**
 * Legt den Wert der fussnoteNummer-Eigenschaft fest.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setFussnoteNummer(String value) {
    this.fussnoteNummer = value;
}

/**
 * Ruft den Wert der fussnoteText-Eigenschaft ab.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getFussnoteText() {
    return fussnoteText;
}

/**
 * Legt den Wert der fussnoteText-Eigenschaft fest.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setFussnoteText(String value) {
    this.fussnoteText = value;
}

}
```

If I add `jakarta.xml.bind` then the FussnoteType class will not be generated at all an I get these errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.5.0:xjc (xjc) on project raw-reporting-core: A Plug-in could not be loaded: "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin: com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.accessors.PluginImpl Unable to get public no-arg constructor
[ERROR] at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:672)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1232)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.findServices(Options.java:979)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.getAllPlugins(Options.java:355)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArgument(Options.java:694)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver$OptionsEx.parseArgument(Driver.java:502)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArguments(Options.java:827)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:231)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.performExecution(AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.java:475)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractJaxbMojo.execute(AbstractJaxbMojo.java:337)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType
[ERROR] at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:659)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:656)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:667)
[ERROR] ... 35 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
[ERROR] ... 43 more
```

The pom is:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.ttt.baw.reporting</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-baw-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <relativePath>../parent-baw-reporting</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>baw-reporting-core</artifactId>
<name>RAW-Reporting-Core</name>
<description>
    - Technisches Modul
    - Die technische Implementierung des Reportings
    - Keine Fachlichkeit!
</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ttt.baw.reporting</groupId>
        <artifactId>baw-config-service</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ttt.baw.reporting</groupId>
        <artifactId>baw-io</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ttt.baw.reporting</groupId>
        <artifactId>baw-results-core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ttt.swaw.pl</groupId>
        <artifactId>swaw-pl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-RC3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.jimfs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jimfs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- @see http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_xjc_basic.html -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/main/resources/reports/core/fussnote/xsd/fussnote.xsd</source>
                </sources>
                <packageName>org.ttt.baw.reporting.core.fussnote</packageName>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                <xsdPathWithinArtifact>.</xsdPathWithinArtifact>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-RC3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 19):

After some days of research my baseline solution for a problem related to the same plugin is the following:

pom.xml file

```
<properties>

    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

    <!-- maven compiler version -->
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <version.maven.jakartaee>9.0.0</version.maven.jakartaee>
    <version.maven.jakarta.xml.bind-api>3.0.0</version.maven.jakarta.xml.bind-api>
    <version.maven.jakarta.ws.rs-api>3.0.0</version.maven.jakarta.ws.rs-api>
    <version.maven.jakarta.activation.api>2.0.0</version.maven.jakarta.activation.api>
    <version.maven.jaxb.impl>3.0.0</version.maven.jaxb.impl>
    <version.maven.jaxb.xjc>3.0.0</version.maven.jaxb.xjc>
    <version.maven.servlet.api>5.0.0</version.maven.servlet.api>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <xjbSources>
                    <xjbSource>src/main/resources/global.xjb</xjbSource>
                </xjbSources>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/main/resources/xsd</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.maven.jaxb.xjc}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.maven.jakarta.activation.api}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.maven.jakarta.xml.bind-api}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.maven.jaxb.impl}</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven.jakarta.xml.bind-api}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven.jakarta.ws.rs-api}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven.servlet.api}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven.jakartaee}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven.jaxb.impl}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In the resources folder, I have a bindings.xjb file and another folder named XSD with the XSD schema.

global.xjb file

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="3.0">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>

        <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>

        <!-- date time adapter -->
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xsi:dateTime"
                       parseMethod="jakarta.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
                       printMethod="jakarta.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime" />

    </jaxb:globalBindings>

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd/schema.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.test.request" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

schema.xsd file

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://services.memorynotfound.com/" elementFormDefault="qualified">


    <xs:complexType name="CourseRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" nillable="false"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="CourseResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="created" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I had to use a newer version of jaxb2-maven-plugin (e.g. 3.1.0), otherwise I got the following ERROR: `Prefix '' is already bound to ''` (see https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1220)

Comment: With springboot 2.6.6 this works like a charm but I need to add the 4 dependencies from the jaxb plugin to the project as well.
I also used the latest version of plugin and dependencies.